# How I can create a private channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to create a support ticket system, everything works except making the channel private, everyone has access to it and when I put overwrites, the ticket no longer opens ... I send you the relevant part of the code

```
guild = ctx.guild
admin_role = discord.utils.get("Admin")
overwrites = {
                admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
            }
            ticketchannel = await guild.create_text_channel(name="ticket {}".format(username), overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
```

Comment: FYI discord.py is no longer maintained and you should start looking for an alternative library

Comment: @mousetail Is this comment helpful? He can still ask the question and use `discord.py` even if it is not maintained any longer.

Comment: While that is true, currently it's very unclear which of the other libraries will be the best, so if he doesn't want to use slash commands, he can stick with discord.py, until another one crystalizes out for him. @mousetail

Comment: I'm not saying the question is bad

Comment: It is because you defined `admin_role` in a wrong way. Do it like this: `admin_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=RoleID)`. You can also say `name="RoleName"` but it is better to go with the ID so you can always change the name without changing the code.

Comment: Oh nice it's work thank <3 <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you're fetching the role is incorrect. You probably should do something like:

```
admin_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=<your admin role ID here>)
```